# Temporary users table or legitimate users table?

Tags: database, database-normalization

I have a freelance web application that lets users register for events.  In my database, I have a t_events_applicants table with the column t_events_applications.user_id with a foreign key constraint linked to the t_users.user_id column.  So this means only users who have registered with my web application can register for my web application's events.

My client would now like to allow non-registered users, users who do not have an entry in my t_user table, to register for events.  These non-registered users only need to provide their name and email address to register for events.

Should I create a t_temporary_user table with columns name and email and then remove the t_events_applicants.user_id fk constraint?  Or should I add un-registered users to the t_user table and then add a column called t_user.type where type can be 'registered' or 'non-registered'?

How do I decide which approach to go with?

A lot of times, I hesitate with either approach.  I ask myself, "What if at a later time, a temporary user is allowed to become a fully registered user?  Then maybe I should have only a t_user table.  But then I also don't feel good about storing a lot of temporary users in t_user."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't that basically be a role?

Create a users table, give them a number of roles (many to many users_roles).
In the roles table, you would add a role that allows registering for events and roles for various rights on the rest of your website.
That way it is easy to promote event-only-users to full-fledged-users (add the correct roles) and it will be possible to add other things later (other events, special subscriptions etc).
Most likely you already have such a system in place anyway..

Comment: I like the roles idea a lot. I am a big fan of keeping all data centralized, but the issue I see with keeping all users in the same table is that we lose the constraints. There would be too many nullable fields, and it is up to the programmers to remember to check for all required fields; including new ones. I know there should always only be one function inserting rows, but I like the added security of preventing bad data from entering the system.

Comment: So you're saying that depending on what roles the user has, more properties should be attached to that user?
In that case, maybe put the fields that only belong to a certain role in the many-to-many table? This will not solve fields that belong to more then one, but less then one roles.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with your second approach: add them in the same table, but with the Type column.  If you create two user tables, you'll have to always check both to find a user, etc.  With two tables, how would you have a constraint from the user to something they create?  Keep it simple, they are a user, just a different type.

If you have a CreateDate or LastLogin date in the users (or some other)  table, you could remove temp users after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like registered users vs. non-registered users has become a false distinction given the new system requirements.  I would keep them all together in a single table.  Keep the site registration information in a separate table.  You don't even need a type column in the combined table since you can determine whether the user is registered with a JOIN to the site registration table.